# Can bash echo command return non-zero exit code?

Tags: bash, unix, echo, sh

Like the title says, is there any case where echo will exit non-zero in bash/sh?

code ex.

```
until monitor_thing_happens; do
  test $retry_counter -eq 0 && echo "thing didn't happen" && exit 1
  let "retry_counter--"
  echo "tries remaining: ${retry_counter}"
  sleep 5
done
```

In the above example, if echo exits non-zero, the && logic breaks, we never exit 1, and we loop forever. Any danger / edge case where echo can exit non-zero?

Comment: Not from `echo` but you can get from `bash` for syntax.  For example try `echo (`.

Comment: I suppose if you did this: `alias echo=garbage` then you get what you deserve, which is a return code of 127 when you try to use it.

Comment: If you are worried don't chain. `test ... && { echo; exit 1; }`.

Comment: Also `echo >file` could fail for permission denied, disk full, etc; those are technically shell errors, not `echo` errors, but nevertheless situations where this simple script fragment fails. And the redirection doesn't have to be adjacent to the `echo`; it could be in a calling script or a faraway `exec`.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, `echo` has a non-zero return status if there's a write error.

Quoting the bash manual:

> 'echo'
>
> echo [-neE] [ARG ...]
>
> Output the ARGs, separated by spaces, terminated with a newline.
>   The return status is 0 unless a write error occurs.

A demonstration:

```
$ cat foo.bash
#!/bin/bash

echo hello
echo "The echo command returned a status of $?" > /dev/tty
$ ./foo.bash > /dev/full
./foo.bash: line 3: echo: write error: No space left on device
The echo command returned a status of 1
$
```

`/dev/full` is a device, similar to `/dev/zero` except that any attempt to write to it will fail with an `ENOSPC` error.

Answer (score 8):

Nope, no risk.  From `man bash`:

> echo [-neE] [arg ...]
>   Output the args, separated by spaces, followed by a newline.
>   **The return status is always 0.** If `-n` is specified, the trailing
>   newline is suppressed. If the `-e` option is given, interpretation of
>   the following backslash-escaped characters is enabled. The `-E` option
>   disables the interpretation of these escape characters, even on systems
>   where they are interpreted by default. The `xpg_echo` shell option may
>   be used to dynamically determine whether or not `echo` expands these
>   escape characters by default. `echo` does not interpret `--` to mean the
>   end of options. echo interprets the following escape sequences:

Emphasis on "The return status is always 0".

From a code quality standpoint, I would recommend [not using `test`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) unless you're forced to for shell compatibility reasons.  In general, use `[[`, but for [arithmetic expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) you can also use `((`:

```
# The generic way
[[ $retry_counter -eq 0 ]] && echo "Thing didn't happen" && exit 1

# The arithmetic way
(( retry_counter == 0 )) && echo "Thing didn't happen" && exit 1
```

Comment: `[[` has some ... unexpected complications when using it for numeric comparisons and for most tests `test`/`[` is just fine and using `[[` only saves you from needing to quote.

Comment: @EtanReisner - Can you elaborate on `[[` having complications?  In addition to not having to worry about word splitting or globbing, using `[[` means not having to escape parens, being able to embed `!` (negation), `&&`, and `||`, and having a few extra comparison operators like `-e`, `-nt`, and `-ot`.  The FAQ link in my answer will give you additional information.

Comment: Compare `bash -c 'bar=4; foo=$1; { [ "$foo" -gt 0 ] && [ "$foo" -lt 10 ]; } || { echo "error"; exit 1; }' - bar` to `bash -c 'bar=4; foo=$1; { [[ "$foo" -gt 0 ]] && [[ "$foo" -lt 10 ]]; } || { echo "error"; exit 1; }' - bar`.

Comment: And yes, the extra operators are useful but that's a specific reason to use `[[` and I said "for most tests" on purpose. I don't see a reason to recommend `[[` over `[` in general for the most part.

Comment: @EtanReisner `((` for arithmetic.  Also compare `[ "$a" == a*a ]` with `[[ $a == a*a ]]`.  `[[` is safer than `[`, I'm with Mr. Llama.

Comment: @cdarke Yes, I specifically said `[[` is awkward for arithmetic and since `[` isn't, I find generally recommending replacing `[` with `[[` as problematic. (`((` is a different conversation and has the same issues, try it.) Yes, not globbing is one of the things already mentioned and that's a quoting issue with the `[` version which I said was the main benefit.

Comment: would these commands ever run the "exit 1" command? if echo returns 0 all the time, then it seems to me that exit 1 would never run. Am I missing something?

Comment: nevermind. I'm still thinking in other languages, where 0 is false and 1 is true. in bash, 0 is good and everything else is bad, and && evaluates further if the previous expression is 0.

Comment: You're referring to an old version of the bash man page. This was changed in git://git.savannah.gnu.org/bash.git commit f6da9f859, 2011-12-29, to: "The return status is 0 unless a write error occurs.". I don't know which release that update first appeared in.

Answer (score 3):

From `help man` (bash):

> Exit Status:
>
> Returns success unless a write error occurs.

**UPDATED**

So if you `echo` to a stream that suddenly fails, you will get another exit code.

Comment: But that's not necessarily `echo` causing the error, it's the shell.  Consider `touch test_file; chmod 000 test_file; >test_file; echo $?`

Comment: @Mr.Llama True it's the shell in this case.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Different comments show risks.
You can try

```
retry_counter=5
while [ retry_counter -gt 0 ]; do
   monitor_thing_happens && break
   (( retry_counter-- ))
   echo "tries remaining: ${retry_counter}"
   sleep 5
done
```

Not without risk ! When the function `monitor_things_happen` resets the same variable `retry_counter` the loop wil run a long time.